# zathura: How do I add a keybind for exec?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, zathura

`zathura` is my default PDF reader. Some files cause it trouble though, and in such cases I run

```
:exec acroread $FILE
```

which automatically opens the same file with Acrobat Reader.

How do I add a key shortcut to the zathura configuration file (`~/.config/zathura/zathurarc`) to do that?

Comment: @FelixBou `$FILE` is the only substring that's treated specially. (It's [here in the source.](https://github.com/pwmt/zathura/blob/master/commands.c#L526))

Answer (score 11):

I recently bumped against a similar problem and, for future reference, here is a workaround:

```
map <C-o> focus_inputbar ":exec acroread $FILE"
```

This will map ctrl+o (or whichever your key is) to open the input bar you would normally open with : and input there that text. You can then press Enter to launch the command. This is far from ideal and still requires a two-key press, but surely faster than writing all the command by hand.

Comment: Is there something like $FILE or % in zathura which brings back the directory (not the filename)?

Comment: @SdidS not to my knowledge, but the zathura documentation is quite lacking (they also have an open issue regarding this here: [gitlab](https://git.pwmt.org/pwmt/zathura/issues/12)).
Anyway: everything after exec is executed by zathura so you could probably try to pass the filename to a script that will then extract the folder from the $FILE and do what you need it to do.
If you need something more specific I suggest trying to open an issue on the gitlab I linked above.

Comment: `@CarloDePieri`, Thanks I've asked it [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/445089/how-to-get-current-document-directory-path-from-zathura) and came up with the same solution as you said.

Answer (score 9):

A slight improvement on the answer offered by CarloDePieri might be this:

```
map <C-o> feedkeys ":exec acroread $FILE<Return>"
```

This avoids the second keypress.

Comment: Note that this will store the line into the input history, but the other methods does not work when the file name contain `"`.

Answer (score 3):

I agree that would be seriously useful, but you can't currently do this.

In the source code, the input-bar `exec` **command mapping** is [here in `config.c`](https://github.com/pwmt/zathura/blob/master/config.c#L418). However, the **shortcut mappings** (starting [here](https://github.com/pwmt/zathura/blob/master/config.c#L436)) which seem to define what functions can be referred to from the configs *don't* mention `exec`. The code isn't structured to easily mix "command" functions and "shortcut" functions yet...

The developers have [a page with methods to contact them](http://pwmt.org/contact/).

Comment: (this answer is outdated, now there's a way) the source code has moved to https://github.com/pwmt/zathura/blob/81e541e3f0554541548be5aa846e4845b9e6fb9a/zathura/config.c#L521 .

Answer (score 1):

While trying to create a mapping that puts the path of the current PDF on the system clipboard, I realized that I have to wrap the whole command in `bash -c "..."`:

```
map y focus_inputbar ":exec bash -c \"printf \\\"$FILE\\\" | xclip -selection c\""
```

For Wayland, the syntax would be:

```
map y focus_inputbar ":exec bash -c \"printf \\\"$FILE\\\" | wl-copy\""
```

Otherwise the command won't do anything.

Comment: Similar to https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/606432/296692, this does not support file names contain `"` or ``\``. A better approach would be to use the `feedkeys` approach combined with writing a bash script to manipulate the file name, if bash is needed (for piping for example).