# How to get current document directory path from zathura

Tags: linux, files, zathura

using `$FILE` (or `%`) in zathura I can run another viewer (e.g. Okular) to open current document like this:

`:exec okular $FILE`

I want same thing but for directories. I want to open containing document folder in my default explorer:

`:exec ranger $DIR`

but this doesn't work. I couldn't find a way to get the directory path. I also tried `:exec ranger % |  sed 's|\(.*\)/.*|\1|'` but this doesn't work. Be able to use pipe in exec might fix this problem.

*p.s. as a workaround I can use `exec nemo $FILE` and nemo uses the file name to select it. But This is just a workaround.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at [the source code](https://github.com/pwmt/zathura/blob/df34d8f17622ace3f6288abb5c789c91e74e92c1/zathura/commands.c#L543), it doesn't look like there's anyway to do this. Zathura simply replaces `$FILE` and `%` with the file path before executing the command.

So you will have to use a workaround anyway. Maybe something like:

```
exec sh -c 'xdg-open $(dirname $FILE)'
```

Or:

```
exec xterm -e 'ranger $(dirname $FILE)'
```

More quoting is really needed here, but I don't know how good Zathura's parser is at handling quotes.

Comment: I tried to use `sed` just like `:exec ranger % |  sed 's|\(.*\)/.*|\1|'` but couldn't find a workaround using this as well.

Comment: @SdidS try something like `exec sh -c 'ranger $(dirname $FILE)'` I'm not sure how good Zathura's parser is at handling quotes.

Comment: that almost work. It says `Must run ranger from terminal`, so I changed `ranger `with `xdg-open`. I think you can update your answer as well to get approved. There might be a solution to directly open ranger (a CLI app) in terminal. Thats another problem. Thank for the answer.

Comment: @SdidS ok, I edited it in and added another command to open a terminal and run ranger

Answer (score 0):

based on @muru answer and to document the solutions, I come up with this workaround as well. I have created a bash script in my `~/bin/selectInRanger` and I just call it from zathura to escape its command line limitations:

```
#!/bin/bash
address=$1;
urxvt -e sh -c "ranger --selectfile='$address'"
```

This is better since it can handle directories with spaces in their name and more flexible. It also selects the `$FILE` passed to it in the opened file explorer.

To map it to a key combination for zathura in `~/.config/zathura/zathurarc` I've added this line:

```
map <C-o> feedkeys ":exec selectInRanger $FILE<Return>"
```

*p.s. this is great specially with Zotero pdf manager and you can easily navigate to appropriate pdf within storage directory, and stuff and ....*

Comment: It is an old thread, leaving my asnwer for future searchers.

Based on this I ended up with `map <C-o> feedkeys ':exec thunar "$FILE"<Return>'` that works directly and escapes whitespaces in PATH.