# How to bind a command to the # symbol in zathura

Tags: configuration, zathura

I want to customize my Zathura to allow me to type `#name_of_a_bookmark`, hit Enter and get sent to this bookmark.

Based on the [answer of another question on this site](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/294876/400005) I figured out that this can be done using the `map` command in the zathurarc file and the command should be similar to this: `map # focus_inputbar ":blist "`.

Then I found out that this doesn't work because `#` is the symbol which starts a comment in the zathurarc file. (Using another symbol like `-` instead of `#` worked so everything else in the command is correct.)

Is there a way to escape `#` in the zathurarc file so I can use it for key bindings?

Comment: Doesn't simply ```map \# ...``` works? (not able to test it right now)

Comment: I don't know - I can try it in a few hours when I'm home again.
The reason I didn't try `\#` is that I didn't realize that `#` is the comment symbol when I tried to use my command. Just now I read more about zathurarc commands and saw this as a comment symbol.

Comment: I've tested it on zathura 0.4.3 (debian 10)

Comment: Nice thanks, I'll accept your answer as soon as I can test it today (provided it works but I don't see a reason why it wouldn't).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply escaping it with a backslash works.

```
map \# focus_inputbar ":blist "
```