# Open a new instance of a pdf file with zathura

Tags: pdf, zathura

I love zathura to read my PDF but there is an important feature I am missing.

How can I open a copy on the current file (in another instance of zathura)?

Thanks for your help!

**Update (solution):**
For my version of zathura (zathura 0.5.2), I just need to add the line

```
map <C-o> exec "zathura $FILE"
```

In .config/zathura/zathurarc

I thanks renzev whose commentary helped me a lot to find this solution!

Answer (score 0):

I love Zathura too! I only started using it recently, so I am not sure if this is the best way to accomplish what you want, but try adding the following to `~/.config/zathura/zathurarc` (create the file if it doesn't exist):

```
map <C-o> feedkeys ":exec zathura $FILE<Return>"
```

This will map `CTRL`+`o` to spawn a new instance of Zathura with the current file.

If you want to actually *copy* your file and open the copy, as opposed to opening the same file twice, then you could use some inline scripting:

```
map <C-o> feedkeys ":exec sh -c 'NEW=$(zenity --file-selection --save --filename $FILE) && cp $FILE $NEW && zathura $NEW'<Return>"
```

This will display a file dialog asking where you want to save the copy and then open the copy. Note that the `zentiy` program is required. Also please note that this will break in case your filename has spaces. If you want it to work for files with spaces, you could create a separate shell script (called something like `zathura_open_copy.sh`) to do the copying and opening:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
OLD=$@
NEW=$(zenity --file-selection --save --filename "$OLD")
cp "$OLD" "$NEW"
zathura "$NEW" & disown
```

And then the `zathurarc` line would be:

```
map <C-o> feedkeys ":exec zathura_open_copy.sh $FILE<Return>"
```

If zathura is installed in a weird way (e.g. not in $PATH, or though flatpak), change `zathura` in the above commands to however you would normally launch zathura from the terminal.

I was able to come up with this hanks to [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/321932/593033)

Comment: Thanks for this interesting and detailled answer! Sadly, it doesn't work for me with zathura 0.5.2, the error message is "pattern no found". I think i understood why : using feedkeys seems to launch the following command "/exec zathura ...." instead of ":exec zathura...". I saw that by just removing the <Return> in the command, in order to show the command. At the contrary, using "focus_inputbar" will indeed send the ":" but seems to no accept a "<Return>".

Comment: I found that with my version, the solution is even simpler! I just added "map <C-o> exec "zathura $FILE"!